# Optimise to find minimum distance

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, constraints, or-tools

I want to be able to divide up a dataset of n points into a variable number clusters (2-10) so that the distance between the points are a minimum subject to a constraint, e.g there are only 5 points per cluster. I don't need to use the whole dataset and am using or-tools at the moment.

Here is what I have now using or-tools:

```
# Create data
Point = collections.namedtuple("Point", ["x", "y"])
################################
points = [Point(1,2), Point(1,2), ..., ..., ...]
################################

# Create my matrix of all points in each cluster
variables = {(i, j): solver.BoolVar("") for i in range(len(points)) for j in range(maxClusters)}

for i in range(len(points)):
    solver.Maximize(***Not sure what to put here***)

# Max number of blue points in each cluster
for j in range(maxClusters):
    solver.Add(sum(variables[i, j] for i in range(len(points))) <= maxBlue)

# Minimum number of blue points in each cluster
for j in range(maxClusters):
    solver.Add(sum(variables[i, j] for i in range(len(points))) >= minBlue)

# Solve
status = solver.Solve()
```

My problem is that I don't know what to write as the objective function to minimise the diameter of each cluster (to ensure the points in that cluster are close together) and maximise the number of points to be included in each cluster.

Comment: I dont know whether I am reading this correctly but it definitely sounds like `kmeans` ie you determine the number of clusters before hand, and cluster the points around their means.

Comment: If the goal is simply to cluster the points (i.e. not necessarily using constraint programming approach), there are many existing implementations in the same package you suggest, which could fit the bill - even if e.g. the number of clusters is not known beforehand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question has two separate parts: choosing an objective function for the clustering problem; and implementing it using OR-Tools.

Regarding the objective function: your choice will have significant impact on the type of solutions you get and the tradeoffs you choose, and so would ultimately depend on the problem you're trying to solve. Having said that, a possible approach is to try to directly optimize a measurement of cluster quality. For instance: maximize the [Dunn Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunn_index), i.e. the ratio between minimal inter-cluster distance and maximal intra-cluster distance.

Here's an implementation, using the OR-Tools CP-SAT solver:

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model
model = cp_model.CpModel()

import collections
import math

# auclidean distance
def int_ad(p1, p2):
    return int(math.sqrt((p1.x-p2.x) ** 2 + (p1.y-p2.y) ** 2))

Point = collections.namedtuple("Point", ["x", "y"])

### DATA
points = [Point(1,2), Point(1,3), Point(2,2), Point(4,3), Point(4,4), Point(6,4)]

distances = [[int_ad(p1, p2) for p1 in points] for p2 in points]

### Parameters
maxClusters = 3
max_in_cluster = 5

# max distance between points
DIST_BOUND = max([i for lst in distances for i in lst]) + 1

### variables

# p,c is true iff point p is a member of cluster c
cluster_points = {(p, c): model.NewBoolVar("cluster_point_%i_%i" % (p, c)) for p in range(len(points)) for c in range(maxClusters)}


#are each 2 points on the same cluster, c
same_cluster_points_helper = {(p1, p2, c): model.NewBoolVar('same_cluster_points_helper_%i_%i_%i' % (p1, p2, c)) 
                       for p1 in range(len(points)) 
                       for p2 in range(len(points))
                       for c in range(maxClusters)} 

# are each 2 points on the same cluster (any cluster)
same_cluster_points = {(p1, p2): model.NewBoolVar('same_cluster_points_%i_%i' % (p1, p2)) 
                       for p1 in range(len(points)) 
                       for p2 in range(len(points))} 


# distance between p1 and p2 if they are not in the same cluster, 0 if they do
inter_cluster_dist = {(p1, p2): model.NewIntVar(0, DIST_BOUND, 'inter_cluster_%i_%i' % (p1, p2)) 
                      for p1 in range(len(points)) 
                      for p2 in range(len(points))}


# distance between p1 and p2 if they are in the same cluster, MAX_DIST if not
intra_cluster_dist = {(p1, p2): model.NewIntVar(0, DIST_BOUND, 'intra_cluster_%i_%i' % (p1, p2)) 
                      for p1 in range(len(points)) 
                      for p2 in range(len(points))}
                      

### Constraints
    
# Max number of points in each cluster
for c in range(maxClusters):
    model.Add(sum(cluster_points[p, c] for p in range(len(points))) <= max_in_cluster)

#each point must be at a single cluster
for p in range(len(points)):
    model.Add(sum(cluster_points[p, c] for c in range(maxClusters)) == 1)

# p1 and p2 are in the same cluster, if they are together in any scpecific cluster c
for p1 in range(len(points)):
        for p2 in range(len(points)):
            model.AddMaxEquality(same_cluster_points[p1, p2], (same_cluster_points_helper[p1, p2, c] for c in range(maxClusters)))

# calculate inter- and intra-distance between points
for c in range(maxClusters):
    for p1 in range(len(points)):
        for p2 in range(len(points)):
            # p1 and p2 are in cluster c?            
            model.AddMultiplicationEquality(same_cluster_points_helper[p1, p2, c], (cluster_points[p1,c], cluster_points[p2,c]))
            
            model.Add(inter_cluster_dist[p1, p2] == distances[p1][p2]).OnlyEnforceIf(same_cluster_points[p1, p2].Not())
            model.Add(inter_cluster_dist[p1, p2] == DIST_BOUND).OnlyEnforceIf(same_cluster_points[p1, p2])
            
            model.Add(intra_cluster_dist[p1, p2] == distances[p1][p2]).OnlyEnforceIf(same_cluster_points[p1, p2])
            model.Add(intra_cluster_dist[p1, p2] == 0).OnlyEnforceIf(same_cluster_points[p1, p2].Not())
                      
# prevent a cluster from having a single element only (it'll cause issues with the Dunn formula)    
for c in range(maxClusters):
    model.Add(sum(cluster_points[p, c] for p in range(len(points))) != 1)

                                                                                     
min_inter = model.NewIntVar(0, DIST_BOUND, 'min_inter')
max_intra = model.NewIntVar(0, DIST_BOUND, 'max_intra')

# since we're going to use integer division, make sure we don't get rounded to zero
scale = 100
min_inter_scaled = model.NewIntVar(0, DIST_BOUND * scale , 'min_inter_scaled')

model.AddMinEquality(min_inter, [inter_cluster_dist[p1, p2] for p1 in range(len(points)) for p2 in range(len(points)) if p1 != p2])
model.AddMaxEquality(max_intra, [intra_cluster_dist[p1, p2] for p1 in range(len(points)) for p2 in range(len(points))] + [1])

model.AddMultiplicationEquality(min_inter_scaled, (min_inter, scale))

# score
score = model.NewIntVar(0, DIST_BOUND * scale, 'score')
model.AddDivisionEquality(score, min_inter_scaled, max_intra)                                                                                   
model.Maximize(score)


### Solve
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()

# optional
# solver.parameters.log_search_progress = True     
# solver.parameters.num_search_workers = 8
# solver.parameters.max_time_in_seconds = 5

result_status = solver.Solve(model)


if (result_status == cp_model.INFEASIBLE): 
    print('No feasible solution under constraints')
elif (result_status == cp_model.OPTIMAL):
    print('Optimal result found, score=%i' % (solver.ObjectiveValue()))
elif (result_status == cp_model.FEASIBLE):                        
    print('Feasible (non optimal) result found')
else:
    print('No feasible solution found under constraints within time')  
    
    
for c in range(maxClusters):
    for p in range(len(points)):
        if (solver.Value(cluster_points[p, c]) > 0):
            print('%i in cluster %i' % (p, c))
```

Which generates the output:

```
Optimal result found, score=100
0 in cluster 1
1 in cluster 1
2 in cluster 1
3 in cluster 2
4 in cluster 2
5 in cluster 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you consider your problem to be distance-specific in that you ensure that you have the minimum distance between the points in a cluster, then you should do `KMeans`:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

res = KMeans(n_clusters = 2).fit(points)
res.labels_
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]) # also [1,1,1,0,0,0] is acceptable since it is a label for a cluster
```